# Elements one under other and scroll not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a small problem when scrolling the page, the elements is one under other, also when I click to do a search, the elements follow the keyboard. I'll show the problem in the screenshots. The intention is category fixed at the bottom, without following the keyboard, also that they aren't one under the other, they need to be one below the other, for example: Action category at the top and the fantasy category at the bottom of the action. remembering that all elements is inside a header. I was thinking in create a div category and scrolling these subcategories inside the div. can anyone help with this CSS or explain me how to do it?

Screenshots

[Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ePW.jpg)

[Without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P82zp.jpg)

[Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64G8U.jpg)

```html
  <body>
    <header>
      <-- rest of code -->
  
      <section>
        <h4>Popular</h4>
        <i class="bi bi-chevron-left"></i>
        <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i>
        <div class="cards">
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h4>Fantasy</h4>
        <i class="bi bi-chevron-left"></i>
        <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i>
        <div class="cards">
        </div>
      </section>
    </header>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Don't post code as image. Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the structure of the html, I already reformulated it and it was just as I wanted. sorry for making this topic for nothing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

replace relative by fixed

```
header section .cards {
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.